# Showing a vertical tangent exists at a given function.

Tags: calculus

I want to apologise in advance for not having this in latex or some sort of neat code, I would be more than happy to learn how though.

Anyway, for the function $y=4(x-1)^{2/5}$ I see there appears to be a vertical tangent at $x=1$, but how can I know for certain the vertical tangent exists at $x=1$? Would I just solve for $f'(x)$, letting $x=1$? But what would that tell me?

Thanks.

Comment: as a side note, if you would like to learn LaTeX, there exists a [very helpful guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) here on our meta site. There is also a stack.exchange site for TeX and LaTeX called [tex.stackexchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) if you have any questions or would like to go into specifics about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f'(1)$ is undefined, you need to consider 
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 1} f'(x).$$ 
You will find that we have
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 1^{+}} f'(x)=\infty$$
and
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 1^{-}} f'(x)=-\infty.$$
In such a situation, where $f(1)$ is defined, we say that the curve $y=f(x)$ has a vertical tangent line at $x=1$.

Answer (score 1):

The slope of the tangent at $(x_0,y_0)$ is $f\prime(x_0)$ and hence the equation is $y-y_0=f\prime(x_0)(x-x_0)$

You can do the calculations now I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you would check if $f'(1)$ tends to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$

$$
\frac{d}{dx}4(x-1)^{2/5}=\frac{8}{5}(x-1)^{-3/5}\\
$$